# How to conditionally merge objects from a single Observable stream?

Tags: stream, reactive-programming, rxjs5

A stream constains the following objects

```
const data = [
  { type: 'gps',   id: 1, val: 1 },
  { type: 'gps',   id: 2, val: 2 },
  { type: 'speed', id: 2, val: 3 },
  { type: 'gps',   id: 3, val: 4 },
  { type: 'speed', id: 4, val: 5 },
  { type: 'gps',   id: 4, val: 6 },
  { type: 'gps',   id: 5, val: 7 }
]
```

In case the ids are the same, the objects are merged. If no id matches up, the object is ignored:

```
[
   [{type: 'gps', id:2, val:2}, { type: 'speed', id: 2, val: 3 }],
   [{ type: 'speed', id: 4, val: 5 },{ type: 'gps',   id: 4, val: 6 }]
]
```

My idea was to group objects with the same type, ending up with two new streams

```
Rx.Observable.from(data)
  .groupBy((x) => x.type)
  .flatMap((g) => ...)
  ....
```

and then to merge/zip them again if the `id` is equal.

I'm not sure how to specify this in Rx and I'm also not sure if this is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to split the stream and merge it back again. You can use `scan` to collect the objects and `filter` out the ones that do not meet to condition

```js
const data = [
  { type: 'gps', id: 1, val: 1 },
  { type: 'gps', id: 2, val: 2 },
  { type: 'speed', id: 2, val: 3 },
  { type: 'gps', id: 3, val: 4 },
  { type: 'speed', id: 4, val: 5 },
  { type: 'gps', id: 4, val: 6 },
  { type: 'gps', id: 5, val: 7 }
]

const generator$ = Rx.Observable.from(data)

generator$
  .scan((acc, x) => {
    if (R.contains(x.id, R.pluck('id', acc))) {
      acc.push(x);
    } else {
      acc = [x]
    }
    return acc
  }, [])
  .filter(x => x.length > 1)
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.23.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.1/Rx.min.js"></script>
```